# Text justification not formatting correctly

Tags: java, formatting, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to make a program that will format text entered so that each line is set to a specific Length and cant go over e.g. 20 and then have the characters format accordingly on each line and have "." pad the gaps to make up the set length.

This is the output I've got so far:

```
 This.is..an..example
 of..text..that..will
 have..straight..left
 and.right....margins
 after formatting ...
```

For some reason the "." are not appearing between after and formatting as well as after the "g" a dot is missing a space is taking its place instead. It seems to always happen's on the last line.

This is what the output should look like:

```
 This.is..an..example
 of..text..that..will
 have..straight..left
 and.right....margins
 after.formatting....
```

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class FormattedPadding {
public static ArrayList<String> fullJustify(ArrayList<String> a, int b) {

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(a == null || a.size() == 0)
        return result;
    int i = 0;
    int currentLength = 0;
    String temp = "";
    for(i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        currentLength += a.get(i).length() + 1;
        if(currentLength > b + 1) {
            result.add(temp);
            temp = "";
            currentLength = 0;
            i--;
            //System.out.println("Intermediate result: " + result);
        }
        else
            temp += a.get(i) + " ";
    }
    if(!temp.equals(""))
        result.add(temp);
    for(i = 0; i < result.size() - 1; i++){
        temp = result.get(i);
        String[] tempArray = temp.split(" ");
        int totalLength  = 0;
        for(int j =0; j < tempArray.length; j++)
            totalLength += tempArray[j].length();

        int[] spaceCount = getSpaceCount(b-totalLength, tempArray.length);
        for(int l =0; l < spaceCount.length; l++)
            System.out.print(spaceCount[l] + " " );
        System.out.println();
        temp = "";

        for(int j = 0; j < tempArray.length; j++){
            temp += tempArray[j];
            for(int k = 0; k < spaceCount[j]; k++)
                temp += ".";
        }
        result.set(i, temp);

    }

    temp = result.get(result.size() - 1);
    if(temp.length() < b){
        while(temp.length() < b)
            temp += ".";
    }
    else if(temp.length() > b)
        temp = temp.substring(0, b);
    result.set(result.size() - 1, temp);
    return result;          
}

public static int[] getSpaceCount(int freeSpace, int numOfStrings) {
    int size = numOfStrings - 1;
    int[] ret = new int[size + 1];
    if(size == 0){
        ret[0] = freeSpace;
    }
    else {
        for(int i =0; i < ret.length; i++) {
            if(size != 0){
                ret[i] = freeSpace % size == 0 ? freeSpace/size : freeSpace/(size + 1);
            }
            freeSpace = freeSpace - ret[i];
            size--;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println("#Enter ");
    String usrInput = BIO.getString();
    String[] items = usrInput.split("\\s+"); // Split where whitespace is encounterd using the RegEx
    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items));
    // ^Split input into ArrayList

    int b = 20; // Line length
    ArrayList<String> result = fullJustify(newList, b);

    for(int i =0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(result.get(i));
    }

    System.out.println(result);

}
}
```

Comment: in fulljustify remove the size()-1 in the second forloop and just put size()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think your code will go to infinite loop if any of the words has length more than "b"

About the issue, you create different logic for the last line

```
temp = result.get(result.size() - 1);
if(temp.length() < b){
    while(temp.length() < b)
        temp += ".";
}
else if(temp.length() > b)
    temp = temp.substring(0, b);
result.set(result.size() - 1, temp);
```

You can remote those part, and change the loop from result.size()-1 to result.size(), so it will cover all lines:

```
for(i = 0; i < result.size(); i++){
```